# "lapply" in R does not work for each element

Tags: r, lapply

```
test.data <- data.frame(a=seq(10),b=rep(seq(5),times=2),c=rep(seq(5),each=2))
test.data <- data.frame(lapply(test.data, as.character), stringsAsFactors = F)
test.ref <- data.frame(original=seq(10),name=letters[1:10])
test.ref <- data.frame(lapply(test.ref, as.character), stringsAsFactors = F)
test.match <- function (x) {
    result = test.ref$name[which(test.ref$original == x)]
    return(result)
}

> data.frame(lapply(test.data, test.match))
   a b c
1  a a a
2  b b a
3  c c a
4  d d a
5  e e a
6  f a a
7  g b a
8  h c a
9  i d a
10 j e a

> lapply(test.data, test.match)
$a
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$c
[1] "a"
```

Hi all,

I am learning to use the apply family in R. However, I am stuck in a rather simple exercise. Above is my code. I am trying to use the "test.match" function to replace all the elements in "test.data" by the reference rule in "test.ref". However, the last column does not work if I turn the final result into data frame. It is even worse if I keep the result as a list.

Many thanks for your help,

Kevin

Comment: I think your problem lies in `test.match`.  If you try running `test.match` on sample data, you can start to see the problem; the expression `which(test.ref$original == x)` does not do what you seem to expect.  The `match` function might be more what you're looking for.

Comment: To expand -- `test.ref$original == x` is doing an element-wise compare of the two vectors.  So it's checking, for column `c`, whether `1==1`, `2==1`, `3==2`, etc., instead of searching for the place where there is a match.

Comment: What's the desired output here? Are you trying to make a data.frame where each column has a different number of rows? That's not how data.frames work.

Comment: `copy <- test.data; for (n_row in 1:nrow(test.data)) {  for (n_col in 1:ncol(test.data)) {    copy[n_row,n_col] = test.ref$name[test.ref$original==copy[n_row,n_col]] }}`
 @user295691 thanks, `match` works! Then why the `which` works in a for loop works (showed above) but not in lapply? I guess the code is doing the same thing as in the `lapply`, right? In addition, what is the difference between `match` and `which`?

Comment: @MrFlick No, I am trying to replace all the elements in a data frame (test.data) by the rule in another data frame (test.ref)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you probably want `match`:

```
do.test.match.df <- function(df, ref_df = test.ref){
    res   <- df
    res[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ref_df$name[ match(x, ref_df$original) ])
    return(res)
}

do.test.match.df(test.data)
```

which gives

```
   a b c
1  a a a
2  b b a
3  c c b
4  d d b
5  e e c
6  f a c
7  g b d
8  h c d
9  i d e
10 j e e
```

This is the idiomatic way. `lapply` will always return a vanilla list. A data.frame is a special kind of list (a list of column vectors). With `res[] <- lapply(df, myfun)`, we're assigning to columns of `res`.

---

Since all your columns are the same class, I'd suggest using a matrix instead of a data.frame.

```
test.mat <- as.matrix(test.data)

do.test.match <- function(mat, ref_df=test.ref){
    res   <- matrix(, nrow(mat), ncol(mat))
    res[] <- ref_df$name[ match( c(mat), ref_df$original ) ]
    return(res)
}

do.test.match(test.mat)
```